# MYSQL SELECT - if x > 100 then x=100

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case

Is it possible to have a SELECT query that takes all values over 100 and returns them as 100? If so, how is that done.

[Here is my SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/043dcb/1)

Here is the query I tried and it does return the values over 100 as 100 but the values below 100 get returned as 0 when I want them to be returned as their original value.

```
SELECT 
    o.steps,
    o.encodedid,
    CASE
        WHEN o.steps > 100 THEN 100
        ELSE o.steps < o.steps
    END 
    AS result
FROM
    activities o
```

Or should I just get the values over 100 and process them with PHP?

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Comment: The zero came from treating that as a boolean expression. Naturally a number is never less than itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly perfect all you need to do is change to

```
SELECT 
  o.steps,
  o.encodedid,
CASE
    WHEN o.steps > 100 THEN 100
    WHEN o.steps < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE o.steps
END 
  AS result
FROM
  activities o
```

So just remove the < o.steps from the second line in your case statement, add another when for the second clause, then just an else to catch everything in between